# Firebase Console Storage Can't Connect To Server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

[image: FIREBASE CONSOLE CAN'T CONNECT TRY AGAIN LATER (IMGUR)]

I'm trying to use the **Firebase Storage** for images in my app. What happened was I wanted to change the name of my app as I've changed my mind on what the name will be, and so respectfully I updated the Firebase Console Project.

Corresponding name spaces were updated. After the rename of the app project I wasn't able to download the **google.json** file anymore. Even after deleting the entire project, and starting from scratch the **google.json** just wouldn't download kept saying there was a problem with the server.

There is another question with this inquiry, but it didn't have a single issue after upgrading to the new Firebase, and the question that is regarding this is specifically about having been upgraded . It took some learning, and there still isn't as much documentation as I'd like. For example, the **FirebaseUI** (ListAdapter) and such. Would solve a lot of my current issues in regards to handling data being moved, updated, deleted, etc.

Is there any way to know if this specific bug issue has been reported? Is it a known issue, and is there a possible timeline? I plan to scale the app once I launch and am afraid to do so as once I do. I will be upgrading the plan to the $25 plan for better simultaneous connections.

Any help would be graciously appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Since a few days ago I was able to download the google.json file. That is great! However, the issue still remains. I cannot use the Storage, and it's giving the same error as the attached image.

Also, I have submitted a ticket with Firebase Support. Communicating with Firebase Support currently via email. Will post updates as I have them.

Comment: sorry you're having issues. I would contact our support team at firebase.google.com/support and let them know the name of the project, etc. so they can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have since also submitted a ticket recently. I shall update the answer to reflect that thank you @MikeMcDonald.